# Working with Text files in QTP

Tags: text, vbscript, text-files, qtp

I need to read the data from an text file and save the read data into an Excel.

The text file contains 111111111122222222223333333333Taaaaaaaassssssss. So here I have read the first 10 characters and save them into a column in Excel and so on for the entire 1 line in the text file.

Trying to do this in QTP, request your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Strategy you could use:

1. Create a COM instance to an excel file through automation. Use `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` to achieve that in QTP. Make the first cell the ActiveCell
2. Open the textfile and perform a `.readall` to store the result in a string
3. Perform an `for each line in split(readAllString, vbNewLine)` to loop over all lines
4. In the body of the For Loop:

   - Loop over the lenght of `line` like: `for characterPosition = 1 to len(line) step 10`, and inside this loop:

     - Do a `mid(line, characterPosition, 10)` to get a set of 10 characters
     - Write the result in the ActiveCell and shift the ActiveCell one column
   - shift the ActiveCell to the first column and the next row
5. Clean up, close the excel file etc.

Step 1 and 2 can be easily looked up on the internets, the other steps are very straight forward VBScript functionality. Give it a try and when you run into problems, add them to your post and we'll see where we can fix it.